# Find and Extract value after specific String from a file using bash shell script?

Tags: linux, shell, perl, unix, sh

I have a file which contains below details :
file.txt

```
+----------------------------------------------------+
|                   createtab_stmt                   |
+----------------------------------------------------+
| CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `dv.par_kst`( |
|   `col1` string,                                   |
|   `col2` string,                                   |
|   `col3` int,                                      |
|   `col4` int,                                      |
|   `col5` string,                                   |
|   `col6` float,                                    |
|   `col7` int,                                      |
|   `col8` string,                                   |
|   `col9` string,                                   |
|   `col10` int,                                     |
|   `col11` int,                                     |
|   `col12` string,                                  |
|   `col13` float,                                   |
|   `col14` string,                                  |
|   `col15` string)                                  |
| PARTITIONED BY (                                   |
|   `part_col1` int,                                 |
|   `part_col2` int)                                 |
| ROW FORMAT SERDE                                   |
|   'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe'  |
| STORED AS INPUTFORMAT                              |
|   'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetInputFormat'  |
| OUTPUTFORMAT                                       |
|   'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetOutputFormat' |
| LOCATION                                           |
|   'hdfs://nameservicets1/dv/hdfsdata/par_kst' |
| TBLPROPERTIES (                                    |
|   'spark.sql.create.version'='2.2 or prior',       |
|   'spark.sql.sources.schema.numPartCols'='2',      |
|   'spark.sql.sources.schema.numParts'='1',         |
|   'spark.sql.sources.schema.part.0'='{"type":"struct","fields":[{"name":"col1","type":"string","nullable":true,"metadata":{}},{"name":"col2","type":"string","nullable":true,"metadata":{}},{"name":"col3","type":"integer","nullable":true,"metadata":{}},{"name":"col4","type":"integer","nullable":true,"metadata":{}},{"name":"col5","type":"string","nullable":true,"metadata":{}},{"name":"col6","type":"float","nullable":true,"metadata":{}},{"name":"col7","type":"integer","nullable":true,"metadata":{}},{"name":"col8","type":"string","nullable":true,"metadata":{}},{"name":"col9","type":"string","nullable":true,"metadata":{}},{"name":"col10","type":"integer","nullable":true,"metadata":{}},{"name":"col11","type":"integer","nullable":true,"metadata":{}},{"name":"col12","type":"string","nullable":true,"metadata":{}},{"name":"col13","type":"float","nullable":true,"metadata":{}},{"name":"col14","type":"string","nullable":true,"metadata":{}},{"name":"col15","type":"string","nullable":true,"metadata":{}},{"name":"part_col1","type":"integer","nullable":true,"metadata":{}},{"name":"part_col2","type":"integer","nullable":true,"metadata":{}}]}',  |
|   'spark.sql.sources.schema.partCol.0'='part_col1',  |
|   'spark.sql.sources.schema.partCol.1'='part_col2',  |
|   'transient_lastDdlTime'='1587487456')            |
+----------------------------------------------------+
```

from above file I want to extract PARTITIONED BY details.

```
Desired output :

part_col1 , part_col2
```

and these PARTITIONED BY is not fixed , means for some other file it might contains 3 or more , so I want  extract all the PARTITIONED BY.

All the values between PARTITIONED BY and  ROW FORMAT SERDE , removing spaces "`" and data types!

Could you please help me with this ?

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -nr '/PARTITIONED BY/,/ROW FORMAT SERDE/p' a.txt|sed -nr '/`/p'|cut -d '`' -f 2|xargs -n 1 echo -n " "
```

Comment: and also instead of having records in file.txt , I have to execute as below : par_col=`beeline --silent -u "$BEELINE_URL" -e "$sql"` where                         
      sql="show create table dvs_wk.par_kst"
     Par_col has the above result but when I doing like :                                                                                                           result=sed -n '/PARTITIONED BY/,/ROW FORMAT SERDE/p' $par_col | sed -n '/`/p'|cut -d '`' -f 2|xargs -n 1 echo -n " " 
 It is giving me an Error.

Comment: sed prints all strings between PARTITIONED BY and ROW FORMAT SERDE (including them), then another sed prints strings only with "`" character, than cut command split string in column by "`" and prints second column (your number), then xargs grabs all numbers and print them with space as separator. May be not best pipeline, but it works on your example.

Answer (score 1):

```
my $text = do { local $/; <DATA> };

my @partitioned = ();

$text=~s#PARTITIONED BY\s*\(([^\(\)]*)\)# my $fulcontent=$1; 
push (@partitioned, $1) while($fulcontent=~m/\`([^\`]+)\`/g);
($fulcontent);
#egs;

print join "\, ", @partitioned;
```

Output:

> part_col1, part_col2

Answer (score 1):

When the layout of your result doesn't matter, you can ask `sed` to consider lines between a start and an end tag, and only print such a line when a field can be found between 2 backquotes.

```
sed -rn '/PARTITIONED BY/,/ROW FORMAT/s/.*`(.*)`.*/\1/p' file.txt
```

Combining the results in a line as desired can be done with

```
printf "%s , " $(sed -rn '/PARTITIONED BY/,/ROW FORMAT/s/.*`(.*)`.*/\1 /p' file.txt) |
   sed 's/ , $/\n/'
```

Answer (score -1):

Small perl script

- read whole file into `$data` variable
- select all between `PARTITIONED BY (....)`
- select into array only elements between `
- print result joined with `,`

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $data = do { local $/; <> };
my $re   = 'PARTITIONED BY \((.*?)\)';

$data =~ /$re/sg;

my @part = $1 =~ /`(.*?)`/sg;

say join ', ', @part;
```